# change the size of panels inside a desktopPane when it's size changes

Tags: java, netbeans

I´m using this code for starting the desktopPane maximized

```
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

When the jDesktopPane displays it's maximized, but the panels inside are the same size and I don't know how to resize them. I want the panels to resize too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `JPanel` inside your `JDesktopPane`, you need to implement layout manager. Then those panel resize based on the layout manager. For example, Here is tutorial how to use [FlowLayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

Comment: Just remember if you do this - it will effect ALL the components in the `JDesktopPane` - this isn't really want a `JDesktopPane` is designed for (not saying you can't do it, but you need to be aware)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented Layout Manager, but used Free Design Instead of Flow Layout, it was easier to me and I got the results I wanted